# Angular 2 - Linking session variable to components variables

Tags: angular

I have 2 different components that import a service.
This service has a property.

I am using this property in the components.
I want the components reference to that value to update when the services property is updated.

The service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SessionService {

    private loggedIn: boolean = false;

    isLoggedIn():boolean{
        return this.loggedIn;
    }


    setLoggedIn(isLoggedIn: boolean){
        this.loggedIn = isLoggedIn;
    }
}
```

The components property:

```
 isSignedIn: boolean = this.session.isLoggedIn();
```

The area of the components html:

```
    <div *ngIf="isSignedIn">
        <sd-header-signed-in></sd-header-signed-in>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf!="isSignedIn">
        <sd-header-signed-out></sd-header-signed-out>
    </div>
```

When I change the sessions value via a button it does not change the value in the component.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
<div *ngIf="session.isLoggedIn()">
   <sd-header-signed-in></sd-header-signed-in>
</div>
<button (click)="session.setLoggedIn(true)">Set session</button>
```

Because your **isSignedIn** variable is evaluated only one time

Here is the full code:

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SessionService {

    private loggedIn: boolean = false;

    isLoggedIn():boolean{
        return this.loggedIn;
    }

    setLoggedIn(isLoggedIn: boolean){
        this.loggedIn = isLoggedIn;
    }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'first-component',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>FirstComponent</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class FirstComponent {
  constructor(public sessionService: SessionService) {

  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'second-component',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>SecondComponent</h2>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class SecondComponent {
   constructor(public sessionService: SessionService) {

  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <button (click)="sessionService.setLoggedIn(true)">Set session</button>
      <first-component *ngIf="sessionService.isLoggedIn()"></first-component>
      <second-component *ngIf="sessionService.isLoggedIn()">
        <button (click)="sessionService.setLoggedIn(false)">Remove session</button>
      </second-component>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  constructor(public sessionService: SessionService) {

  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App, SecondComponent,FirstComponent  ],
  providers: [SessionService],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And working plunker:
[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xILJjHLtP96NeZsZVOhL?p=preview)

Comment: The button that sets the value in the service is done from a different component. I thought this way would be the same as referencing the value in the components ts file, where is assigned to session.isLoggedIn anyway. I tried putting it as *ngIf="session.isLoggedIn()" and *ngIf!="session.isLoggedIn()" but it is still not working.

Comment: must you subscribe or something?

Comment: I have a console log in the session service which displays the loggedin property each time after it is set, and the buttons do set it to false and true. The issue is the component does not display a difference, the buttons are in a different component which also has the session service. I am not sure if this would cause an issue?

Comment: Solved it, I was putting the service into the providers on my component.ts file

Comment: Oh yes because of this the session service is not global singelton. good!

Comment: if you hit f5 the variable is back to false, is there a solution?